# mongodb using $in for matching array with array inside aggregate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform an aggregate query in MongoDB. My target is to check if any values within an array exists in another array and conditionally introduce a third variable accordingly.

For example, I have an array A => ["a", "b"] and another array B => ["a", "c", "d"]
So in this case as "a" exists in both A & B, they should match.

```
aggregate.push({
                "$addFields": {
                    "canClaim": {
                        $cond: [{
                            $in: [["a", "b"], ["a", "c", "d"]]
                        }, 1, 0]
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: could you show some example documents?

Comment: Actually, my real document is different.  I just posted a similar simple example. If the above example is acheived, I can change accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$addFields": {
    "c": {
      "$setIntersection": [
        "$a",
        "$b"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$match": {
    "c.1": {
      "$exists": true
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y6tVQHYaWlC)

Comment: Great. $setIntersection is the solution for me. Thanks man